# Two pages, same database query, different results

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

Help me please.
I'm writing my student project on Python 2.7 + Google Application Engine.

I have next pages:
/ - main page where I have list of uploaded files

/delete/file_blob_key - handler to delete record from datastrore

In both handlers I use next statement:

```
bases = dbModels.kbEntity.all()
```

On '/' page this statement returns list of records in the datastore

On '/delete/file_blob_key' page this statement returns empty list

What the problem?

Handlers:

```
#===============================================================================
# Handler to delete file from server by key
#===============================================================================
class DeleteHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, resource):
        base = dbModels.kbEntity.all().filter('kbKey=', resource).fetch(1)[0]
        base.delete()
        self.redirect('/')

#===============================================================================
#
#===============================================================================
class IndexHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def getAllBasesTable(self):
        bases = dbModels.kbEntity.all()
        bases.order('-kbUploadDate')
        bases = {}
        template = JE.get_template('./templates/TPLBasesTable.html')

        values = {
            'bases': bases
        }
        return template.render(values)

    def get( self ):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        template = JE.get_template('./templates/TPLIndex.html')
        values = {
            'bases': self.getAllBasesTable()
        }
        html = template.render( values )
        self.response.out.write( html )
```

Comment: You have to show more of the code for both handlers cause it really doesn't make sense if you have the exact same thing in both handlers..  to return different results and since the second one is for deleting stuff why do you need to show the list of all entities..?

Comment: I've added handlers to my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
I've changed

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
```

for

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

Now all queries works fine

Answer (score 2):

In the line 3 of the `getAllBasesTable` you are overriding the `bases`. So delete the `bases = {}` and you should have your desired result.

Comment: Already, but problem was not solved. As I say in '/' handler i got all records from datastore, in /delete/blob_key handler - nothing